# saving "mocked" mongodb collections in version control

Tags: mongodb, git, version-control

I am developing on two machines (switching PC and laptop during the week) and try to find the best way to synchronize a limited amount of dummy data in the mongodbs running on each machine.

My first quick & dirty idea was to track the relevant files, containing the collection data inside of a db folder (inside my project folder) by Git.

I saw for example files named e.g. *collection-0-1858325258041703863.wt* which seem to contain what i am after. 
However i am not sure about the rest e.g. *index-1-1858325258041703863.wt* files, *sizestorer.wt*, *WiredTiger.wt* etc..
**Which are the files i have to track and which are the ones i can ignore?**

I am aware that i could create a mock server with only json files and that saving binaries in VC is bad, but still i am curious if this way is possible (Mainly because working with MongoCompass is way easier than editing json files)

Comment: Are all these machine connected through internet or intranet?

Comment: the two machines are connected over internet